# Media link of a video available on OTT platform

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, media-player, ott

I am looking to integrate videos freely available on OTT platforms in India.

For example http://www.sonyliv.com/details/full%20movie/4709492313001/The-Butterflies-In-My-Head-%7C-Short-Film

However this is the web link to the video file. I am not able to fetch the media link to this and all such videos. Is it possible to do what I am trying and if so what should my direction of implementation be

Answer (score 0):

I think if you look at the terms of use on that site (which are at the bottom and are, not very helpfully, hidden every time you scroll down) the conditions don't really allow what you are proposing, other than by linking to their site as your link above does, or sharing via their share options (Google + and Facebook for the example you show above).

So you can solve this technically with varying degrees of ease, depending on whether the source sites hide the media manifest URL's or use dynamically generated URL's etc, but it's probably worth making sure you are not going to get into issues over rights first.